# Converting Datetime and TImespan to String

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller, timespan

```
        public Nullable<DateTime> SessionStartDT { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan SessionStartTM { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> SessionEndDT { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan SessionEndTM { get; set; }
        public string Start
        {
            get
            {
                return SessionStartDT?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + SessionStartTM.ToString();
            }
        }
        public string End
        {
            get
            {
                return SessionEndDT?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + SessionEndTM.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I am getting a compilation error on my return statements. Also I am getting "feature null propagation operator is not available in c# 5". How can I change this ?

Comment: Change your project compiler options to use a newer version of C#.

Comment: Please can you tell me how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

`SessionStartDT?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` `null propagation ?.` is a feature of **C#6**. You cannot use it with `version`<6.
 You got two options.

- Either update ur `C#` version.
  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St
- Remove operator return `SessionStartDT.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + SessionStartTM.ToString();`

**Note:-** If `SessionStartDT`can be `null`. Apply null check.

Comment: I updated my Language version to C#6. It did not work. SHould I update my target framework version as well ? Right now I am using 4.5.2. SHould I update that to 4.6 or higher ?

Comment: Yeah, similarly you can do that too. But If it's not your project. Contact your team before upgrading. Though it should have worked without framework upgradation.